# What does it mean for an inner product to be conjugate linear in the second entry?

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Let $G$ be a group and $L^2(G) = \{f: G \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \}$.  Now define an inner product on $L^2(G)$ by
$$\langle f, g \rangle = \sum_{x \in G}f(x)\overline{g(x)}$$
Where $\overline{g(x)}$ is the complex conjugate.

I know what it means for the inner product described above to be linear in $f$, i.e. $\langle f + g, h \rangle = \langle f, h \rangle + \langle g, h \rangle$ and $\langle \lambda f, g \rangle = \lambda \langle f, g \rangle$. What does it mean for the inner product to be "conjugate linear" in $g$?

Comment: It implies that $<f,f>$ is non-negative. In case $<f,f>=0$ implies $f=0$ and it defines a norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that for any scalar $s\in C$ and for all vectors $f,g_1,g_2$  we have $<f,s g_1+ g_2>=\bar s\cdot  <f,g_1>+<f,g_2>.$

Comment: $\mathbb{C}...$